# Creating a background process under HHVM

Tags: php, vagrant, daemon, background-process, hhvm

I have a php script that I'd like to run in the background after the user submits a form.
The simplest solution would seem to be to use a fork like the following:

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid) {
    // Parent process. Do nothing.
} else {
    // Child process. Put background script in this block.
}
```

This works well from the command line, but has been "disallowed" for browsers ([HHVM can't use pcntl_fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426255/hhvm-cant-use-pcntl-fork)).

---

The next simplest solution is to use

```
exec( 'php ' . $path . ' > /dev/null &' );
```

where $path would point to my background script. Again, this works perfectly on the command line, but when run from the browser it would produce the error

> "Failed to initialize central HHBC repository: Failed to open file
>   /var/www/.hhvm.hhbc"

I didn't even have a /var/www/ folder, so out of desperation I created one and symlinked the .hhvm.hhbc from /home/vagrant/.hhvm.hhbc into the new directory. I then got hit with a

> "Failed to initialize central HHBC repository: Failed to initialize
>   schema in /var/www/.hhvm.hhbc:"

I went a little crazy with chmod 777's throughout my html folder and on the original .hhvm.hhbc, but it did me no good.

---

It's a really bad user experience to run my background script in the foreground, because then there's a ~15 second pause after the submit button is clicked before the user can see the page again. Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using "pagelets".  This lets you spin up a new, background PHP request.
Docs here: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/master/hphp/doc/threading

Comment: This worked! Here are some additional resources that helped me figure out how to [configure](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Runtime-options) and [use](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/master/hphp/runtime/ext/server/ext_server.php) pagelets.